# Why do i need DateFormat?

Tags: java, date

I'm a beginner and I got this code from Lynda, and I don't know why there should be DateFormat in this code:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class date {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Date d =new Date();
        System.out.println(d);

        GregorianCalendar gc =new GregorianCalendar(2009, 1, 29 );
        gc.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE   ,1);
        Date d2 =gc.getTime();
        DateFormat df =DateFormat.getDateInstance();
        String sd =df.format(d2);
        System.out.println(sd); 
    }
}
```

while there is`Date d2 =gc.getTime();` that get the time from `GregorianCalendar` why I can't just write 
        `System.out.println(d2);`

Comment: `System.out.println()` will prints any thing inside `toString()` method.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you output the `Date` object directly, its [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) function is called implicitly, giving you a string in the format `dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy`, which may or may not be what you want.

Using  `DateFormat` implementation lets you choose the date format that seems appropriate for your task. The method used in that code, [`getDateInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance--), gives you a formatter that uses a format based on the current locale. There are lots of other ways you can get `DateFormat` instances, depending on what you want to do, but that one is a reasonable general-purpose formatter for dates in the current locale.